# Schedule Server iOS Push Notifications

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, server-push

I implemented server side iOS push notifications.

I was wondering if it is possible to schedule server side iOS push notifications just like the local ones?

Something like:

```
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
        'schedule' =>  ?
    );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. You have to do some logic on your server that it sends the notification at the given time.

See [The Notification Payload @ APNS Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use one of the intermediate services like [AlertRocket](http://www.alertrocket.com) or [UrbanAirship](http://www.urbanairship.com). They both have APIs that will allow you to schedule pushes for a later time and will communicate with APNS on your behalf.